# 19.04 Gnome panel selection area

Tags: gnome, taskbar

In 19.04 the Gnome panel selection area for the extenstions on the left of the panel overlaps the panel into the desktop or full screen application. The extensions in the centre and on the right of the panel do not overlap and there is a red line at the bottom of the panel when they are selected. On the left of the panel the red line appears below the panel and makes using fullscreen applications difficult. For instance if I try to click on a Chrome tab and I click on the upper half of the tab, instead of opening the tab the extension above it opens.

This didn't happen in earlier versions of Ubuntu and is only happening since I upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04 yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

It was a Gnome extension (IPFinder) causing the problem. Feel free to delete the question, I should have done more research before asking it.